# Optimize JSon array parsing

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, optimization

I am working on an app where I receive information via GET. I need to parse the received JSon array into a Java object. Each JSon object has at least 10 fields, and I'm working with 50 objects. I had measured the execution times and I'm getting bad results while parsing these objects.

The objects will be displayed in a listview populated by a custom adapter, showing the first 12, then the next 12 and so on (when I reach the bottom of the list I load the next 12).

Right now I'm parsing the objects on post execute. My question is: how can i accelerate the parsing process, do I have to parse the json objects just when i need them(loading 12 by 12)? 
Should I use threads for the parsing process so I don't load too much the main thread, when should I use threads?

I've thought different solutions but all of them require time to code and to test, time that I don't have so, could you tell me which would be the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Android Query Library](https://code.google.com/p/android-query/) and use the simple JSON AJAX Parsing built in:

```
public void asyncJson(){

        //perform a Google search in just a few lines of code

        String url = "http://www.google.com/uds/GnewsSearch?q=Obama&v=1.0";             
        aq.progress(dialog).ajax(url, JSONObject.class, this, "jsonCallback");

}

public void jsonCallback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status){

        if(json != null){               
               //PARSE YOUR JSON       
        }else{          
                //ajax error
        }

}
```